# All select option for list with Checkbox android compose

Tags: android, checkbox, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack

When I click on Select option it should checked all the list. I have a dialog which have a list of users and check box. When I Checked All option and set value true for all list it will not reflect in the dialog. when I close and open the dialog it will checked all the items. I know that value in the list is set true but it is not recompose the items in the list. or not update the Checkbox state.

[image]

ViewModel Code

```
var listOfRolesMaster = mutableStateListOf<AnnnouncementListData>()
```

API Collecting Data

```
 vm.listOfRolesMaster = data.data.users.toMutableStateList()
```

Data Class

```
data class AnnnouncementListData(
var id: String,
var name: String,
var isCheck: Boolean,
```

)

Function for open dialog and check the items

```
@Composable
fun RoleSearchDialog(vm: AnnouncementViewModel) {
Dialog(
    onDismissRequest = {
        vm.isSendRoleDialog.value = false
    },
    properties = DialogProperties(
        usePlatformDefaultWidth = false, // experimental,
    )
) {
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .width(320.dp)
            .height(400.dp)
            .padding(all = 16.dp)
            .background(
                color = Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(15.dp)
            ),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {

        /*Header*/
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(bottomStart = 15.dp, bottomEnd = 15.dp)),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
        ) {

            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(16.dp)
                    .align(Alignment.CenterVertically),
                text = "Select Users",
                style = TextStyle(
                    fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.opensans_bold)),
                    fontSize = 16.sp,
                    color = Color(0xFFB20710)
                ),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Start
            )

            Image(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(48.dp)
                    .padding(10.dp)
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
                    .clickable {
                        vm.isSendRoleDialog.value = false
                    },
                painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_attachment_remove), contentDescription = "Icon"
            )
        }

            var allCheckedState = remember { mutableStateOf(vm.isAllRoleSelected.value) }


            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(start = 16.dp, top = 5.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start,
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "All",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(start = 10.dp, end = 16.dp)
                        .weight(0.8f)
                        .align(Alignment.CenterVertically),
                    style = TextStyle(
                        fontFamily = FontFamily(
                            Font(
                                resId = R.font.opensans_semibold
                            )
                        ),
                        fontSize = 12.sp,
                        color = Color(0xFF121212),
                    )
                )

                Checkbox(
                    checked = allCheckedState.value,
                    onCheckedChange = {
                        allCheckedState.value = it
                        vm.listOfRolesMaster.forEachIndexed  { index , item ->
                            vm.listOfRolesMaster[index].isCheck = it
                        }
                        vm.isAllRoleSelected.value = it
                    }
                )
            }


            vm.listOfRolesMaster.forEachIndexed { index, item ->

                Log.e(TAG, "ALL_FLOOR1 item ${item.isCheck}")
                var myState by remember { mutableStateOf(item.isCheck) }
                Log.e(TAG, "ALL_FLOOR myState = $myState == ${item.isCheck}")

                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(start = 16.dp, top = 5.dp),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start,
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = item.name,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(start = 10.dp, end = 16.dp)
                            .weight(0.8f)
                            .align(Alignment.CenterVertically),
                        style = TextStyle(
                            fontFamily = FontFamily(
                                Font(
                                    resId = R.font.opensans_semibold
                                )
                            ),
                            fontSize = 12.sp,
                            color = Color(0xFF121212),
                        )
                    )

                    Checkbox(
                        checked = item.isCheck,
                        onCheckedChange = { isChecked ->
                            item.isCheck = isChecked
                        }
                    )
                }
       
        }
    }
}
}
```

when i assign "item.isCheck" to mystate. the value is true but mystate value return false.

```
var myState by remember { mutableStateOf(item.isCheck) }
```

Comment: I edited my answer to add some missing code. Does the answer resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Even when you use `mutableStateListOf()`, Jetpack Compose only can detect when you add, remove, or replace an item. It does not detect when you modify an item in the MutableList.

So instead of modifying the `isChecked` variable of an existing object with `vm.listOfRolesMaster[index].isCheck = it`, instead assign a new modified item to the MutableList. You can easily do so by using the Kotlin [`copy`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html#copying) function like this:

```
onCheckedChange = {
    allCheckedState.value = it
    vm.listOfRolesMaster.forEachIndexed  { index , item ->
        vm.listOfRolesMaster[index] = item.copy(isChecked = it)
    }
    vm.isAllRoleSelected.value = it
}
```

Also update the other piece of code with

```
Checkbox(
    checked = item.isCheck,
    onCheckedChange = { isChecked ->
        vm.listOfRolesMaster[index] = item.copy(isChecked = isChecked)
    }
)
```

As a sidenote, to prevent you from stumbling into that kind of mistake, it is recommended to only use val in data classes instead of var. So also consider to update your data class as follows:

```
data class AnnnouncementListData(
    val id: String,
    val name: String,
    val isCheck: Boolean
)
```

By that, you force yourself to only modify properties using the `copy` function, which then will result in a recomposition.